# Как отловить Ctrl+C в telnet приложении

Tags: c#, telnet

Написал для одной задачки простенькую консоль. Подключаюсь по 500 порту из Putty, ввожу команду "tail" и получаю в бесконечном цикле вывод на экран всего что валится в логфайл. Проблема: не соображу как словить Ctrl+C

```
case "tail":
    LastCommand = "tail";
    long LastCounter = 0;
    while (ConsoleServer.ConsoleServerFlag) {
        var list = LOG.ConsoleTextBuffer.Get(LastCounter);
        if (list != null) {
            foreach (var i in list) {
                PutString(Client, i.Text, ConsoleClient.ColorTranslate.ContainsKey(i.Clr) ? ConsoleClient.ColorTranslate[i.Clr] : null);
                LastCounter = i.Counter;
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66633/discussion-on-question-by-mkp---ctrlc--telnet-).

Answer (score -1):

Внутри цикла читать из потока в только когда NetworkStream.DataAvailable == true.
Подвисания/приостановки на Read() в таком случае не происходит.
Искать в прочитанном символ \x03.
Ну и собственно прерываться.

Alex78191, спасибо.

Comment: Пометьте как решение